# Bash script: suming columns by unique name {name:number}

Tags: bash

not a native speaker so the best way to explain is to give example, of what I have to do.

> name1: 15
>
> name2: 20
>
> name1: 8
>
> name3: 30

Now this is a short example of the output I get when greping from a file.
Now I'm not sure how to handle suming of those numbers, so that the final solution is

> name1: 23
>
> name2: 20
>
> name3: 30

There are several ways to solve this, and the only way I currently see is something involving Arrays, which I was told is not the best way to think about in Bash.

Thank you for your help and sorry if the question has been asked before.

Comment: Please post the progress you have made so far writing your bash script.

Comment: Lol who upvoted this? It's been asked a million times before...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NF{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' File
```

This would work for all non-empty lines.

Example:

```
$ cat File
name1: 15

name2: 20

name1: 8

name3: 30
```

Sample:

```
$ awk 'NF{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' File
name1: 23
name2: 20
name3: 30
```

Comment: Hmmm I'd be careful with the `/name/` test without explanation, I'm pretty sure this is a placeholder and OP actually has other values here

Comment: Better consider `:` too as a delimiter. That would give you a fault proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for previous answer.. I didn't read your question properly (not enough coffee yet).

This might do what you want.

```
declare -A group_totals

while read -r group value ; do
  group_totals[$group]=$(( group_totals[group] + value ))
done < <(grep command_here input_file)

for group in "${!group_totals[@]}" ; do
  echo "$group: ${group_totals[$group]}"
done
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to sum grouping by first column's value rather than return a global sum

Comment: Ah yes, I'm on another planet this morning. :-)